# Objective-C pre-compilation error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, header, prefix

I'm compiling a big iPhone app and am getting 24 of the same error...

> cc1plus: note: obsolete option -I-
>   used, please use -iquote instead cc1:
>   error: -I- specified twice

This error is repeated 24 times for the same prefix header file. Any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you by any chance using the option `-I-`?

Comment: Hi Chuck - do you know where (file perhaps?) I would check to see that?

Comment: Can you post your prefix header file?

Comment: Do you have any directory with an space on it?

Comment: Your error is in .h file which is being included in 24 different souyrce files, hence the count.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix header is being included in 24 source files. The option -I- is causing the error in the prefix header and the error is repeated 24 times.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this error when I began using XCode 4.  For me, it ended up being my Schemes in XCode.  I was naming them something like "MyApp - Ad Hoc".  I renamed the Scheme to be "MyApp_Ad_Hoc" instead, and it cleared this up.  Hopefully, this will help some people.